# hapi.js Lab testing, server.js always returns 404 status

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

I'm in the process of evaluating hapi.js. All was going well until I started writing tests. Basically I'm trying to test the status code as the first step. however I cannot proceed further. Server.inject always returns 404. I tested the same code by running the server and sending http requests using fiddler ( an http request simulation tool like postman ). This is successful. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm following the exact steps as in many tutorials online. The test code is as follows.

```
var Lab = require("lab");
var server = require("../server/index.js").server;
var lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
var code = require("code");

lab.test("home", function (done) {
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/"
    }
    server.inject(options, function (response) {
        var result = response.result;
        code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
    });
});
```

The assertion never seems to be passing successfully, I have made sure the routes are available.

EDIT: As Matt Harrison has correctly  pointed out, I'm in fact loading the routes asynchronously.

How to test in these scenarios?

Comment: What is in the index.js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks ok with your test. To prove it, if you put this in your index.js file it should work:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: 4000 });

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('ok');
    }
});

exports.server = server;
```

Without seeing what's happening in your `index.js` file I can only make an educated guess. But here goes anyway…

One possibility is that you're adding the `GET /` route asynchronously and it isn't in the routing table when your test gets run. Why might this happen? Some plugins don't call the register callback immediately because they need time to set themselves up. If you're registering your routes in this callback they're not loaded when your test gets run. For example this will fail with 404 for your test:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({ port: 4000 });

var fakePlugin = function (server, options, next) {

    setTimeout(next, 500);
};

fakePlugin.attributes = { name: 'fake' };

server.register(fakePlugin, function (err) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('ok');
        }
    });
});

exports.server = server;
```

**SOLUTION:**

To solve this issue, you just need to delay your tests until all plugins have finished loading. There's a few possible ways to do that. Here's one I like:

Add a `before` to your test that delays running tests until server emits a `pluginsLoaded` event:

```
...

lab.before(function (done) {

    server.on('pluginsLoaded', done);
});

...
```

And you just need to make sure you emit that in your `index.js`:

```
server.register(..., function (err) {

    server.route({
        ...
    });

    server.emit('pluginsLoaded');
});
```

Comment: You're right, the routes are loaded in such callbacks, how can I test in such a situation?

Comment: Awesome, you just made me to go for Hapi as this was the only bit stopping me

Comment: Indeed, this solution is right thing to do. Just one remark: instead to catch the "pluginsloaded" event, you should catch the "start" event (http://hapijs.com/api#internal-events)

Comment: For the solution you will also need to create the event with `server.event('pluginsLoaded')` otherwise you get an error emitting that event: https://hapijs.com/api#serveremitcriteria-data-callback